# Bug or feature? Click on Tab does not give the buffer with the shown buffer name

Tags: tabbar

Below two screenshots.

The first one before the click on a tab:

[image]

---

The second one after the click on the tab:

[image]

---

As you can see above the click on the tab does not give the buffer with the name shown in the tab.

The core of the issue is that Emacs 29.0.60 lucid GUI does not update the names shown in the tabs when a buffer is killed from one of the other tabs.

Is something wrong with my expectation that after killing a buffer the tabs no more able to show this buffer change their labels to the buffers they will actually show when clicking these tabs?

Below a third screenshot after the click on the second tab showing `.emacs`:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug to me ... I assume that Eli Z. will accept bug reports for the developmental master branch via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  In the past, I have also used the developer mailing list for certain questions about potential bugs, versus features ...  In either case, be prepared to always spend time with the developers subsequent to filing any bug report to help track down the issue and test potential fixes, etc.

Comment: Reported: bug#6257

Comment: (That's likely the wrong bug number - too low.)

Comment: bug#62575 - thanks ... copy/paste problem. 39 new bugs since my last bug report two days ago ... makes 20 bug reports per day ... is Emacs so buggy or is it business as usual? (I haven't yet any experience in that area).

Comment: Not that I know anything about `tab-bar-mode` but from what I read in the Emacs manual, it has to do with window  configurations rather than buffers. There is a different facility of (per-window) `tab-lines` that has to do with buffers. At this point, I am inclined to believe that it is a misunderstanding of what `tab-bar-mode` does, rather than a bug, but I don't know enough about it to say for sure.

Comment: @NickD : this is a problem with updating the label of the single Tab-bar Tab which isn't triggered for all Tabs when a buffer is killed. Both Tab-bar and Tab-line tabs show buffer names. The Tab-line shows tabs with names of the through the window already seen buffers, The Tab-bar label shows the buffer name of the buffer the Tab current active window looks at. Comparing Emacs to a desktop (see .emacs.desktop file) the Tabs in the Tab-bar are what the OS calls Workspaces and Emacs sometimes "root windows", sometimes "frames", sometimes "window configurations".

Comment: The click on the Tab-bar Tab is what triggers the Tab to re-evaluate what it is displaying. So the update due to killed buffer is done at the time of the click and not at the time the buffer is killed. This results in misleading labeling on the tab.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks for the explanation! I didn't try very hard but I found the labeling confusing even without killing buffers. I may come back to `tab-bar-mode` eventually and explore some more, but for now I'm steering clear.

Comment: Yes, Tab labeling is confusing because it shows a buffer name instead of *"I am workspace #1 (or #2 or #3, ...) with current window showing buffer with the name X. Best you have Tabs with one window per Tab showing one buffer. Than you can switch between the buffers by switching the tabs. To view a specific buffer you can: click on the buffer name in the Tab-bar or in the Tab-line or on the name in the modeline (to cycle through all). If you want you can. prevent Help and other buffer to be shown in a new created window. This reduces the confusion a bit.

Comment: Where are the up-votes for a good question? Describing a problem already present in version 28.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

##### *It's MAYBE a [bug#62575](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=62575) ( reported  2023-03-31 )*

---

Below the steps required to reproduce the "bug":

1. ~ $ emacs -Q
2. Menu -> Options -> Show/Hide -> Tab Bar (gives Tab *scratch*)
3. 1x click on rightmost * in the Tab Bar to create a new Tab (gives 2x *scratch* Tabs)
4. With the rightmost (second) Tab open ~/.emacs (gives 1x *scratch* and 1x .emacs Tabs)
5. 2x click on rightmost * in the Tab Bar to create twp new Tabs (gives 1x *scratch* and 3x .emacs Tabs)
6. with rightmost Tab active kill the .emacs buffer [C-x k] (the Tabs label turns  to *scratch the other two Tabs labeled .emacs keep their labels, so there are 1x *scratch*, 2x .emacs, 1x *scratch* Tabs)
7. *click the second Tab labeled* .emacs' (result: the label of the Tab turns to *Messages*. the Tab Bar shows *scratch* *Messages* .emacs *scratch* )

The bug: the third Tab still keeps its  .emacs  label and the click on the second Tab labeled  .emacs  does not show the .emacs file, but the buffer *Messages*.

---

Below a patch you can place in the Emacs initialization file which will update Tab Bar Tabs labels on killing a buffer (provided by the Emacs development team):

```
(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook
          (lambda ()
            (let ((tabs (reverse
                         (mapcar (lambda (tab) (1+ (alist-get 'index tab)))
                                 (tab-bar-get-buffer-tab nil t nil t)))))
              (run-with-timer
               0 nil
               (lambda (tabs) (dolist (tab tabs) (tab-bar-select-tab tab)))
               tabs))))
```

---

Below the responses from the Emacs development team:

> Can reproduce in 30 (db7e95531ac36ae842787b6c5f2859d0642c78cc) and 28.2
> (tagged) -- so even if this is a regression, it would not be a recent
> one.

> Essentially, the reported bug can be summarized as: the tab names on a
> tab bar do not respond to situations where a buffer has been deleted.

> In addition, I noticed that this behavior extends to renaming a buffer
> as well (tried it in 30, not in 28.2).  The reproducer is to replace (6)
> above with the following, and observe that the other tabs do not update
> their names until you click on them.

> `C-x x r hello RET`

---

> After looking at the code, I'm not sure this is a bug.  The tab names are just labels, although they are conveniently set to the name of the buffer in the window to be selected when the tab is current.  But otherwise they are just labels.  When you click on the tab, its name is updated to reflect the buffer shown in the selected window, so **I think Emacs is behaving correctly, although it might be a bit
> unexpected.**

Comment: Can you link to the bug? Hint: https://debbugs.gnu.org/

Comment: @Drew: thanks for the hint. Have added the link.