# Bug or feature? Window Tab Line disappears when *xxx* buffers (*scratch*, etc.) are viewed in window

Tags: tabbar

**Context**: *GNU Emacs 29.0.60 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, cairo version 1.16.0, Xaw3d scroll bars) of 2023-03-30, Development version 4508a024e818 on emacs-29 branch; build date 2023-03-30. Linux Mint 21 (Vanessa) Cinnamon.*

After detecting problems with usage of the tab-bar ([Bug or feature? Click on Tab does not give the buffer with the shown buffer name](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76593/bug-or-feature-click-on-tab-does-not-give-the-buffer-with-the-shown-buffer-name)) I have switched to usage of the tab-line, but also here I run into a problem:

If the window is showing one of the `*xxx*` buffers like for example `*scratch*` the tab-line disappears and I am no more able to get back by clicking a tab on a tab-line to the other buffers just because the tab-line is no more there.

I have already set via Custom the tab-line-exclude-modes to nil in the `.emacs` file:

```
(custom-set-variables
  '(tab-line-exclude-modes nil))
```

but this does not change the described behavior.

What am I missing to achieve a stable tab-line keeping to stay there for any buffer I am viewing in the window?

P.S. The easiest work-around this problem is sure just not to view any of the buffers which make the tab-line disappear ... or just not to use the tab-line or tab-bar at all switching the buffers by clicking on the buffer toggle area in the modeline.

Am I alone here with having problems with the tab-bar and tab-line?

How do you switch to a specific buffer out of a huge number of buffers?

Comment: **Q**: "*How do you switch to a specific buffer out of a huge number of buffers?*"  **A**:  `C-x b` provides built-in buffer switching, with completion and an optional list of buffers.  `C-x C-b` provides a built-in list of buffers from which to chose.

Comment: @lawlist : does it explain how it comes that the problems with the tab-bar or tab-line are not an issue worth attention here because both of the GUI elements are just not in use and no-one cares if they are buggy  (motto: not all what is available must be used)?

Comment: One should expect that the developmental master branch will be extra-buggy, and if so inclined, then be prepared to assist the development team track down those bugs and fix them.  Previous stable releases should be less-buggy, but will still require bug reports and participating with the development team to track down and fix them.  I am using a modified version of the old `tabbar.el` by David Ponce, and an outdated version of Emacs containing some custom modifications ...  As to certain bugs in Lisp code, rather than written in C, you may even be able to fix some of those yourself.

Comment: @lawlist The problems I am facing seem to be already there at least since version 27, so the developmental master branch is not really an issue. Thanks for your response - I will try to make it from the keyboard only without the mouse clicks and take over at least a part of the "responsibility" for proper functioning of the code fixing as much issues by myself as possible or at least finding another way of doing same things in case of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below an excerpt from the initialization file listing `(setq  tab-line-exclude-modes nil)` as a command which solved for me the in question described issue.

```
;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Show a tab-line, i.e. Window Tab Line a tab-bar above a Window
;; global-tab-line-mode is an autoloaded interactive byte-compiled Lisp
;; function in  tab-line.el  
;; (custom-set-variables '(global-tab-line-mode t)) or 
(global-tab-line-mode t)
;; Prevent that some modes does not show a tab-line upon their window:
;;   tab-line-exclude-modes is a variable defined in  tab-line.el  file
(setq  tab-line-exclude-modes nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do you switch to a specific buffer out of a huge number of buffers?

One possibility is to use a completion framework like `ivy`, `vertico` or whatever.  In my case, I bound `C-x b` to `ivy-switch-buffer` and buffer-switching is fast and efficient.